# Scrollx hide search inputs

Tags: datatable

I have a little problem.
When adding my table the element `"scrollX": true`, the search entries disappear.

CODE:

JAVASCRIPT

```
function parametrosTabla6(tabla) {

    var tabla2 = $(tabla).DataTable({
        'paging': true,
        'searching': true,
        'ordering': true,
        'orderCellsTop': true,
        'order': [
            [0, 'desc']
        ],
        "scrollX": true,
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                'responsivePriority': 1,
                'targets': 0
            },
            {
                'responsivePriority': 2,
                'targets': -1
            },
            { "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all" }
        ],
        'responsive': true,
    });

    var len = $('#datos thead tr:eq(1) th').length;
    $('#datos tfoot:eq(0) th').each(function (i, e) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (i == len - 1) { } else {
            $(this).html('<input style="width:100%" class="form-control" data-column="' + (i + 1) + '" type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
        }

        $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (tabla2.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                tabla2.column(i).search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });
    });

}
```

HTML/CSS/PHP

```
 <table id="datos" class="table table-hover display drtresponsive nowrap" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Nº Pedido</th>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Nº Telefono (fijo-movil)</th>
                        <th>Fecha Venta</th>
                        <th>Correo Enviado</th>
                        <th>Estado Pago</th>
                        <th>Expedicion</th>
                        <th>Fecha Envio</th>
                        <th>Fecha Entrega</th>
                        <th>Recibido</th>
                        <th>Anulado</th>
                        <th>Usuario Venta</th>
                        <th>Ultimo usuario editado</th>
                        <th>Acciones Disponibles</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot style="display:  table-header-group">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nº Pedido</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Nº Telefono (fijo-movil)</th>
                            <th>Fecha Venta</th>
                            <th>Correo Enviado</th>
                            <th>Estado Pago</th>
                            <th>Expedicion</th>
                            <th>Fecha Envio</th>
                            <th>Fecha Entrega</th>
                            <th>Recibido</th>
                            <th>Anulado</th>
                            <th>Usuario Venta</th>
                            <th>Ultimo usuario editado</th>
                            <th>Acciones Disponibles</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($result)) {
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    switch ($row['recibido']) {
                                        case 0:
                                            $row['recibido'] = "NO";
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            $row['recibido'] = "SI";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    switch ($row['correo_confirmacion']) {
                                        case 0:
                                            $row['correo_confirmacion'] = "NO";
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            $row['correo_confirmacion'] = "SI";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    switch ($row['factura']) {
                                        case 0:
                                            $row['factura'] = "NO";
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            $row['factura'] = "SI";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    switch ($row['anulado']) {
                                        case 0:
                                            $row['anulado'] = "NO";
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            $row['anulado'] = "SI";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    require 'mod/tabla_facturas.php';
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo "<tr>0 results</td>";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "<td colspan='100%'>0 results</td>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

[image: When the inputs are fine]

[image: When the inputs disappear]

Comment: A couple of options: (1) Move the data input fields into a second header row (this will require [`orderCellsTop`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop)). (2) Remove the `scrollX` option and instead wrap the table in a `<div style="overflow-x: auto;">...</div>` as explained in [this thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/128441/#Comment_128441) from the DataTables external forum.

Comment: @andrewJames All right, the second option is the most feasible. I think he needs a break hahaha
Thanks very much buddy!

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to show future visitors exactly how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

You have two options:

1. (The one I have chosen) Put the `overflow-x:auto` in parent div.
2. Clone the thead and add the inputs.

> ```
> var len = $('#datos thead tr:eq(1) th').length;
> $('#datos thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#datos thead');
> $('#datos thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (i, e) {
>     var title = $(this).text();
>     if (i == len - 1) {
>         
>      } else {
>         $(this).html('<input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
>     }
>
>     $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
>         if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
>             table
>                 .column(i)
>                 .search(this.value)
>                 .draw();
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

Add the [orderCellsTop](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) option to the datatable.